# How to validate if a B-tree is sorted

Tags: algorithm, sorting, data-structures, b-tree

I just had this as an interview question and was wondering if anyone knows the answer?

Write a method that validates whether a B-tree is correctly sorted. You do NOT need to validate whether
the tree is balanced. Use the following model for a node in the B-tree.

It was to be done in Java and use this model:

```
class Node {
List<Integer> keys;
List<Node> children;
}
```

Comment: Do you know what SBT looks like?

Answer (score 0):

One (space-inefficient but simple) way to do this is to do a generalized inorder traversal of the B-tree to get back the keys in what *should* be sorted order, then to check whether that sequence actually is in sorted order. Here's some quick code for this:

```
public static boolean isSorted(Node root) {
    ArrayList<Integer> values = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    performInorderTraversal(root, values);
    return isArraySorted(values);
}

private static void performInorderTraversal(Node root, ArrayList<Integer> result) {
    /* An empty tree has no values. */
    if (result == null) return;

    /* Process the first tree here, then loop, processing the interleaved
     * keys and trees.
     */
    performInorderTraversal(root.children.get(0), result);
    for (int i = 1; i < root.children.size(); i++) {
        result.add(root.children.get(i - 1));
        performInorderTraversal(root.children.get(i), result);
    }
}

private static boolean isArraySorted(ArrayList<Integer> array) {
    for (int i = 0; i < array.size() - 1; i++) {
        if (array.get(i) >= array.get(i + 1)) return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

This takes time O(n) and uses space O(n), where n is the number of elements in the B-tree. You can cut the space usage down to O(h), where h is the height of the B-tree, by not storing all the elements in the traversal and instead just tracking the very last one, stopping the search early if the next-encountered value is not larger than the previous one. I didn't do that here because it takes more code, but conceptually it's not too hard.

Hope this helps!